# How to add 'N' to the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The background behind this question is that I amtrying to call a stored procedure using dapper in my WinForm project.
I wanted to let the stored procedure handle the if else statements.
I am having some troubles with one of the parameters which happens to be a NVARCHAR field.

Details to be explained below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Account_GetAccount @Code VARCHAR(4), @Name NVARCHAR(20), @AccountType_Code CHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
IF(@AccountType_Code = '')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Account]
        WHERE [Code] LIKE '%' + @Code + '%'
        AND [Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Account]
        WHERE [Code] LIKE '%' + @Code + '%'
        AND [Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
        AND [AccountType_Code] = @AccountType_Code
    END
END

EXECUTE Account_GetAccount @Code = '', @Name = N'現', @AccountType_Code = '';
```

If I included N in front of the '現' then I can get results correctly.
However, if I omitted the N in then no results will return...

I wanted to move N into the stored procedure.
Is there a way to achieve this?

I have tried

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Account_GetAccount @Code VARCHAR(4), @Name NVARCHAR(20), @AccountType_Code CHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
IF(@AccountType_Code = '')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Account]
        WHERE [Code] LIKE '%' + @Code + '%'
        AND [Name] LIKE N'%' + @Name + '%'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Account]
        WHERE [Code] LIKE '%' + @Code + '%'
        AND [Name] LIKE N'%' + @Name + '%'
        AND [AccountType_Code] = @AccountType_Code
    END
END

EXECUTE Account_GetAccount @Code = '', @Name = '現', @AccountType_Code = '';
```

and

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Account_GetAccount @Code VARCHAR(4), @Name NVARCHAR(20), @AccountType_Code CHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
IF(@AccountType_Code = '')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Account]
        WHERE [Code] LIKE '%' + @Code + '%'
        AND [Name] LIKE '%' + 'N' + @Name + '%'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Account]
        WHERE [Code] LIKE '%' + @Code + '%'
        AND [Name] LIKE '%' + 'N' + @Name + '%'
        AND [AccountType_Code] = @AccountType_Code
    END
END

EXECUTE Account_GetAccount @Code = '', @Name = '現', @AccountType_Code = '';
```

but both failed

Comment: Have you tried with `@Name = N'%現%'` in the `EXECUTE`?

Comment: `N'some text'` yields a value of type `NVARCHAR`, while `'some text'` yields a value of type `VARCHAR`. So no, what you want to do can't be done. You need to pass a value of the proper type.

Comment: You're trying to unscramble an egg - by the time the stored procedure's code is running, the data has already been corrupted.

Comment: The `N` before the string literals indicates that it's a "National Character" string, aka. Unicode. You're close with `N'%' + @Name + '%'` but you're still mixing nvarchar and varchar types. Try `N'%' + @Name + N'%'` and then when invoking the proc be sure to use `@Name = N'現'`